# iOS Objective-C get VPN IP programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, vpn

I use a third-party app to connect a VPN, and we can get the detail information in `Settings->VPN->information`. How can I get the `Assigned IP` programmatically in our app by Objective-C?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *address = @"error";
struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
int success = 0;

// retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
if (success == 0) {
    // Loop through linked list of interfaces
    temp_addr = interfaces;
    while (temp_addr != NULL) {
        if( temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
            // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
            if ([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"utun1"])
            {
                // Get NSString from C String
                address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
                NSLog(@"ifaName: %@, Address: %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name],address);
            }
        }

        temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
    }
}

// Free memory
freeifaddrs(interfaces);
```

`address` will have the  assigned IP Address

Comment: This approach worked for me. The header files needed are: 
```#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>```

Answer (score 0):

This is working on iOS 14:

```
- (NSString *)getVPNIPAddress
{
    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;

    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0)
    {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL)
        {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name]);
                // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                if(
                   [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] containsString:@"tun"] ||
                   [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] containsString:@"tap"] ||
                   [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] containsString:@"ipsec"] ||
                   [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] containsString:@"ppp"]){
                    // Get NSString from C String
                    struct sockaddr_in *in = (struct sockaddr_in*) temp_addr->ifa_addr;
                    address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa((in)->sin_addr)];
                }
            }
            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }

    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    return address;
}
```